# Web API using Entity Framework to query by multiple columns

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Using EF6, I'm creating a Web API project. When I add a Controller, the EntityKey is the default column queried ("Id"), which works fine. I want to add additional columns to query within the same table via the API, which I'm unable to get to work.

For example, I can query Id (/api/CtrlName/123456), but if I want to query via say a Title column, /api/CtrlName?title="value", it always comes back with a NotFound message.

Is there a simple tutorial to set this functionality up within the Controller?

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Article))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetArticle(string id)
    {
        Article article = db.Articles.Find(id);
        if (article == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(article);
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof (Article))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetArticleByTitle(string title)
    {
        Article article = db.Articles.Find(title);
        {
            if (article == null)
                return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(article);
    }

    private bool ArticleExists(string id)
    {
        return db.Articles.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }

    private bool ArticleExistsTitle(string title)
    {
        return db.Articles.Count(b => b.title.Contains(title) ) > 0;
    }
```

Comment: Post your code, it's probably a small thing

Comment: Edited original post with code.

Comment: Take a look at this article on Attribute Routing: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2.  Note that you are currently treating `id` and `title` as the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you that the route is the same, but when I did do ?title=, it would hit the GetArticleByTitle method instead of GetArticle and just fail to find a result, even though when looking at the debugger, I can see a result that matches (based on the returned column values from the entity data/database). At any rate, I created a mapping for that method [Route("api/Articles/{title}")] and like my previous code, I'm still getting a NotFound returned. This seems to be an EntitySet/database issue rather than the routing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that .Find() only works on the Primary Key. In order to work on other columns, you must use .Where (e.g. db.Articles.Where(i => i.Title.Equals(title)).